# Get Words Between Brackets Ext JS 4.2.1

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

Below is the text :

```
"Les quantités vendues dans Agil (84) et Generix (0) ne sont pas cohérentes".
```

I would like to get both the strings `84` and `0` which are in brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does it has to do with `ExtJS` ?
Anyway, here's the solution:

```js
let fn = function(str) {
    let arr = [],
        i = -1,
        start = false;
    str.split('').forEach(function(c) {
        if (c === ')') {
            start = false;
        }
        if (start) {
            if (arr[i] === undefined) {
                arr[i] = '';
            }
            arr[i] += c;
        }
        if (c === '(') {
            start = true;
            i++;
        }
    });
    return arr;
};

console.log(fn('Les quantités vendues dans Agil (84) et Generix (1) ne sont pas cohérentes'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) and [`new RegExp()`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/classic/RegExp.html) to get the required result.

**RegExp**

- \ For characters that are usually treated literally, indicates that the next character
  is special and not to be interpreted literally.
- **^** Matches beginning of input.
- **+** Matches the preceding item 1 or more times. Equivalent to {1,}.
- **\d** Matches a digit character in the basic Latin alphabet. Equivalent to [0-9]
- (x) Matches x and remembers the match. These are called capturing parentheses.

**DEMO**

```js
const str = "Les quantités vendues dans Agil (84) et Generix (0) ne sont pas cohérentes",
  regex = new RegExp(/\(([^d)]+)\)+/g),
  regexBracket = new RegExp(/[()]/g);

let matches = str.match(regex).join('_');

console.log(matches.replace(regexBracket,'').split('_'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression object for matching text according to a pattern:

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
    var 
        exp = new RegExp(/\(([^)]+)\)/, 'g'),
        matches,
        numbers = Array();
    while ((matches = exp.exec("Les quantités vendues dans Agil (84) et Generix (0) ne sont pas cohérentes.")) != null) {
        numbers.push(matches[0]);
    }
    console.log(numbers);
});
```

Comment: OP wants only inside of `()`. check  with this value `"50 Agil (84) et Generix (0) test 15"`

Comment: @NarendraJadhav You are right, I've updated the answer. Thanks for that note, I use regex rarely.